# replace a substring using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a string like:      `b"a`

and I want to replace it with string:     `]b"a`

The quotation mark here is very annoying, maybe some one can help me here?

Comment: Could you explain the statement `The quotation mark here is very annoying`? It might help us solve your problem as I suspect it probably isn't as simple as it appears to be.

Comment: I solved it. Thank u, Morton!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'b"a' | sed 's|b"a|]&|'  ## & represents the matched string;
```

Outputs:

```
]b"a
```

- Use `g` to replace all matches in a line: `sed 's|b"a|]&|g'`

Similarly in Bash if you have it stored in a variable:

```
A='b"a'
B=${S/b\"a/]b\"a}   ## B=${S//b\"a/[b\"a} to replace all occurrences 
echo "$B"
```

Outputs:

```
]b"a
```

Comment: Why ``echo`` when you can `<<<` ?

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko Yes you can. However the OP didn't say where he gets his string so using `echo` would give less explanation. We also don't know if he's really using `bash` despite giving the tag to it. Despite being out of scope mentioning `<<<` may also be instructive but still optional.